# Is there a graph with FOSS licenses detailing what can be linked with what?

Tags: licensing, foss, chart

I'm looking for a chart like this:

[image]

Basically something that tells you whether an app with a given license can be linked with a library of a given license.

Does such a thing exist?

Comment: One caveat: GPL is not necessarily compatible with GPL.

Comment: @mario: The graph was just an example.

Answer (score 4):

It's unlikely such a thing, as described, exists: there are many definitions of what constitutes a FOSS license and even more licenses. Such a graph would never be canonical or authoritative.

However, GNU and the Free Software Foundation (and by extension, Wikipedia) have taken great pains to document which licenses are GPL-compatible (and subsequently "FSF-approved"):

- [List of FSF approved software licenses on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FSF_approved_software_licenses)
- [GNU's list of Various Licenses and Comments About Them](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.html)

Comment: There's a table for various GPL/LGPL versions here too: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#AllCompatibility

Comment: Your logic is a bit confusing to me. It's true that there are quite a lot of licenses, and some are more free than others, but for any given pair of licenses, there is an answer. Such a graph would never be *complete*, but it could certainly be based on authoritative legal advice.

Comment: @Jefromi if legal interpretations were clear and unambiguous, there'd be no need for courts, lawyers, or judges. Whether a license is compatible with another is subject to interpretation, and there is no single authoritative source for that interpretation. Even the lists mentioned in my answer and sparkie's comment are the legal opinions of one body, the Free Software Foundation.

Comment: The existence of ambiguity doesn't mean that all cases are ambiguous, and most of us don't need absolute authority. For example, the FSF saying a license is GPL-compatible is going to be good enough, even though it's not as absolute as a supreme court ruling.

Comment: @Jefromi there is no authoritative answer, and a graph is not an alternative to sound legal advice. The *only* lists that exist are ones that specific bodies have published based on their own interpretation of the legal issues surrounding the licenses they vet. It's why the FSF only talks about specific licenses within the context of its own, normative definition of what a free software license is and makes no claim about others. Licensing is not a simple issue that can be summed up in a graph.

Comment: Okay, I understand all of what you're saying, but the simple truth is that not every single project, especially small FOSS ones, is going to be able to consult a lawyer on everything. The next best thing, things like the links you gave, is still an answer, despite not being authoritative.